Is the nvstreammux installed with deepstream?
So I am trying to run a sample program from deepstream-6.1 which I installed on Jetson Nvidia jetpack-5.0.1, cuda-11.4, cudnn-8.2.4,tensorrt-8.2.5 and I am getting the error as below.
opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-6.1$ deepstream-app -c source1_csi_dec_infer_resnet_int8.txt
ERROR: create_multi_source_bin:1457: Failed to create element 'src_bin_muxer'
ERROR: create_multi_source_bin:1550: create_multi_source_bin failed
ERROR: create_pipeline:1327: create_pipeline failed
ERROR: main:697: Failed to create pipeline

Quitting
App run failed

I tried finding solution and referred this link, I checked - gst-inspect-1.0 nvstreammux and it shows error No such element or plugin 'nvstreammux'.
I tried reinstalling the deepstream-6.1 but still I found the same issue every time. Can anybody help me find a solution. I just want to run the sample from deepstream to make sure it is installed properly.
